# How to trigger the mouse over video action in a YouTube.com video (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, video, google-chrome-extension, youtube, mouseover

for my chrome extension,
I'm trying to get the current time in a YouTube video,
which works via

```
var timeArr = document.getElementsByTagName("ytp-time-current");  
  for (var i = 0; i < timeArr.length; i++) {
      var currentTime = priceEls[i].innerText;
  }
```

but only when the video is 'focused', when the browser can see the timestamp, otherwise the HTML isn't updated to show the current time.

How can I trigger that mouseover effect on behalf of the user?

Comment: Can you not extract the time from the video element itself? It would be more reliable than parsing a UI element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to parse the UI to get the time of a YouTube video. It's an HTML5 `<video>` element with all associated capabilities, e.g. inherited from [`HTMLMediaElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement):

```
let video = document.querySelector("video.html5-main-video");
let currentTime = video.currentTime; // Fractional, in seconds
let totalDuration = video.duration;
```